# What is the use of ^ in patindex in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

When I execute this

```
select PATINDEX('%[0 ]%', '03/SI/00807/18-19')
```

I am getting `1`.

By using `^` like this:

```
select PATINDEX('%[^0 ]%', '03/SI/00807/18-19')
```

I am getting `2`.

Comment: [LIKE (Transact-SQL) - Arguments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#arguments)

Answer (score 1):

**[^]** Allows you to match on any character not in the [^] brackets (for example, [^abc] would match on any character that is not a, b, or c characters) Whereas

**[ ]** Allows you to match on any character in the [ ] brackets (for example, [abc] would match on a, b, or c characters)

**_**   Allows you to match on a single character

**%**   Allows you to match any string of any length (including zero length)

Answer (score 0):

`[^abcd]` means: any one character EXCEPT a,b,c or d

```
select PATINDEX('%[0 ]%', '03/SI/00807/18-19')
```

The first character in your string which is (0 or space) is the 0 in the first place, so patindex returns 1.

```
select PATINDEX('%[^0 ]%', '03/SI/00807/18-19')
```

The first character in your string which is (*neither* 0 *nor* space) is the 3 in the second place, so patindex returns 2.